# The Nodejs is not recognizing the placeholder command ${ Var result }

Tags: node.js

I have declared 2 variables that are numbers using the Node.JS
when I ask the template String ${ } to execute the sum this command is not recognized by Node.JS

```
var a = 5
var b = 3
console.log('The sum of a + b is ${a + b}') 
The sum of a + b is ${a + b} // -> this is the result
```

the Node.JS is not showing the sum result when is typed ${ }
Does anyone know why the Node.JS is not recognizing the template String ${ }?

Comment: Because you're not using the correct syntax for [templating literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)? It uses backticks, not apostrophes.

Comment: Template literals only work when you use backtick `. It won't work with normal quotes or double quotes

Comment: Thank you Mike Kamermans and Thatkookooguy... issue fixed..